# What features of an ASP.Net website available only in Internet Explorer browser?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser

I have offers to build my business website using ASP.Net technology.

I'm worried that this way will tight me into the web browser IE of Microsoft.

So my question is is there any points of ASP.Net web that are not compatible with other web browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera?

In other words, what are things that will only run on IE?

**Summary of issue(s)**

1. Use older .NET Framework with the latest browsers (.Net Framework below version 4.5 and IE10, IE11; all versions are the latest at the time of this answer)
2. Write IE-specific client-site JavaScript code, but that would be unrelated to ASP.Net; it is rather the developer IE-tied coding habit
3. Using Ajax for server control(s); years ago back in the 2005 but not for now 2013

Comment: ASP.Net is not browser dependent. It generates HTML

Comment: I think it does as the answers below

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET detects browser capabilities (to use CSS, JavaScript etc.) and generates proper HTML for respective browser from downlevel and up.

The only problem you may encounter if you use older .NET Framework (below version 4.5 which is current at the time of this answer) with the latest browsers (such as IE10, IE11 - latest at the time of this answer). Then it may not recognize the browser and generate incorrect HTML/JavaScript.

Otherwise non MS-browsers have no problem accessing and vieweing ASP.NET Web sites.

---

P.S. Of course you can encounter problems if you write IE-specific *client-site* JavaScript code, but that would be unrelated to ASP.NET

Comment: This is only partially true.  It's only the case if you're using certain features, like Ajax.  In general, for 99.99% of what you write, there is no difference in output between browsers.  It certainly was the case years and years ago (back in the 2005 time frame) but not anything modern.

Comment: Actually there's huge difference. IE, especially older versions have a lot of proprietary client stuff. From DOM things like "innetText" to missing features such as "getElementsByClassName" there're many many things you may encounter in client code. Oh and if you mean difference in generated HTML - just google or search SO for "IE10 _doPostBack" or "IE10 SCRIPT5022 error".

Comment: As I said, it only applies to things like Ajax server controls (or your own custom javascript).  Using normal, non-ajax server controls this is not an issue.  My point is that this is only an issue when it actually matters (when there are legitimate browser differences).  Your post made it sound like it renders non IE browsers differently, which is not the case.. it's all based on browser capabilities (in fact there's a browsercap file you can modify if it gets out of date).

Comment: The IE10 issue is an out of data browsercap file, this doesn't require updating any code, just updating the browsercap file on the server

Comment: Where did I made a point that it renders differently for non-IE browsers? Could you please point it in my answer? I thought I stated the opposite *non MS-browsers have no problem accessing and vieweing ASP.NET Web sites*

Comment: What you didn't make clear was that this generally only affects things like Ajax, not standard HTML rendering of most server controls.

Answer (score 1):

First, i'd like to point out that just because you use asp.net doesn't mean you have to use the Microsoft supplied server controls.  You can use third party controls, or write your own.  Or you can use minimal server controls to support things like Themes, Master Pages, etc.. and do everything else in your own framework.

The point here is that "using asp.net" can mean a lot of different things.

Having said that, if your developer is going to use stock asp.net controls (or maybe a few third party ones) then you should understand that asp.net is not tied to any particular browser, but it can be tied to specific browser capabilities.

ASP.NET uses something called a browsercaps file, which identifies the browser by it's user agent string, and this tells asp.net which capabilities the browser supports.  Such as what level of JavaScript, or what level of CSS, etc.. IF a new browser comes out, you may have to update this browsercaps file for it to be supported as an "uplevel" browser.  downlevel browsers are rendered without special features.

IE is not favored in these detections, and it does not tie you to IE in any specific way, unless your developer writes IE specific code or HTML.

In general, these do not come into play in a normal asp.net web site, unless you need to do uplevel things, like Ajax, and you're using the ASP.NET Ajax server controls.

So much of this is "it depends on how your developer implements things".  Make sure you specify to your developer that you demand full browser compatibility, and specify which browser versions you want to support.  Understand that supporting older browsers may cost more money because older browsers have many more quirks and incompatibilities.

So to answer the question you posed in the title:

**There are no features of ASP.NET that are only available in Internet Explorer**

However, there are plenty of features that are not available in some browsers (like text-only browsers such as Lynx.. obviously), particularly older browsers, or some mobile browsers, etc..

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. Though, the two things you help to point out 1) IE specific code and 2) AJAX server control worry me. @1 the developer coding habit will often raised this issue. @2 really a stopper for me :(

Comment: Would you please give me some examples of those the IE-tied AJAX server controls?

Comment: @NamG.VU - I'm not sure how you have misunderstood me.  I was very clear.  THERE ARE NO FEATUERS OF ASP.NET THAT ARE ONLY AVAILABLE IN INTERNET EXPLORER.  Even the Ajax stuff I mentioned.  It's all about browser capabilities, not specific brands of browsers.